# Spring Boot + Keycloak via SAML - Invalid reqeuests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, saml-2.0

I've been trying to set up a Keycloak locally with docker to be able to login to our application with SAML 2.0.

Versions used:

```
Keyloak 19.0.3
Spring Boot 2.7.3
```

When I call an REST endpoint of the application, I am correctly redirected to Keycloak (redirect to `http://localhost:8085/realms/PocRealm/protocol/saml`). But I don't get a login form but the message: "We are sorry ... Invalid Request" .
I then see the following entry in the Docker console logs.

```
2022-10-07 12:22:41,972 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-104) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=e026f301-c74b-4247-bb0a-58cdb651ae00, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=client_not_found, reason=Cannot_match_source_hash
```

These are my configurations:

application.properties

```
# Spring Server Settings
server.port=8081

#Keycloak Settings
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8085
keycloak.realm=PocRealm
keycloak.resource=pocApp
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username

#SAML Settings
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.keycloak.signing.credentials[0].private-key-location=classpath:credentials/myKey.key
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.keycloak.signing.credentials[0].certificate-location=classpath:credentials/myCert.crt
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.keycloak.assertingparty.metadata-uri=http://localhost:8085/realms/PocRealm/protocol/saml/descriptor
```

KeycloakConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
    {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper simpleAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        simpleAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider =
                keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(simpleAuthorityMapper);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy ()
{
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
@Override
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager()
{
    return new HttpSessionManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
{
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(groupsConverter());

    // @formatter:off
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .mvcMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
            .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))
        )
        .saml2Logout(withDefaults());
    // @formatter:on
}

private Converter<OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> groupsConverter() {

    Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> delegate =
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter();

    return (responseToken) -> {
        Saml2Authentication authentication = delegate.convert(responseToken);
        Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = (Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> groups = principal.getAttribute("groups");
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        if (groups != null) {
            groups.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).forEach(authorities::add);
        } else {
            authorities.addAll(authentication.getAuthorities());
        }
        return new Saml2Authentication(principal, authentication.getSaml2Response(), authorities);
    };
}
}
```

I don't see the problem and even after hours of research I can't get anywhere at this point and maybe someone here can help me? Maybe there is a better approach in general? (OpenID-Connect instead of SAML is unfortunately not an option)

Thank you